# Sitecore Forms string length validator not working for other languages text

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation

I am using a Sitecore Forms string length validator which is working perfectly fine for English content, however if I am providing content in say Japanese language then in that case it is not working.

For example the validation doesn't work for this text when given more than the limit which is by default 512.

報内容3情報内容4情報内

Same when given English language content then working fine.

Has anyone gone through such scenario or can suggest anything, does the option is custom validation only or is there anything provided by Sitecore here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to create a custom validation message item on sitecore.
First you need to create an item on /sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations.
[image]
[image]
After you need to create a custom code on Visual studio to render the message with the rule that you want, for example, field is required. After that you need to include your validation item on "
Allowed Validations" /sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic/Single-Line Text if its a single line field as example.
[image]
Doing that you need to go to form builder insert you new validation rule on field that you want to implement.

[image]

Create a message for all languages that you need. you can use this blog post as a reference. https://ndiasitecore.wordpress.com/2021/01/22/custom-validation-message-sitecore-forms/

Comment: Thanks nick, your solution works so awesome !!! :)